# How do we add other SE sites as options for flagging?

Tags: support, flagging

I just flagged a post to close, as it belongs on [biology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/).

When I went to the "belongs on another site" flag, it only gave Pets Meta as an option.

Does the system dynamically determine what sites to put on the list, or is that a list which is currently empty and needs to be populated?

If it is an empty list, I recommend putting Biology as one of the sites, and possibly DIY, but that's really for another question depending how this one gets answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't a configuration we really support while sites are in beta - moderators can migrate posts at their discretion (often with a bit of coordination), so you can flag them as 'other' and let the mod know why it should go somewhere else.

This starts building up what we call a migration history, where the system tracks how many posts this site sent to others, and how many of them were rejected (closed as anything other than duplicate) once migrated. We then look at this data upon graduation, and if it makes sense to set up a migration path based on historical data, then we will.

For now, just flag as other :)

Comment: "while sites are in beta", really?  Sites on SE are in beta for years.  SE sites have beta lengths longer than Google products.  :-P

Comment: @JoshDM It's a good measure of when we're _positive_ that a site is not going to close. We wouldn't close a site that has been in beta for 3 years unless it turned into a ghost town, but even the _tiny_ possibility still has to be considered when we're thinking about places content people have contributed to us is going to land. When a site is ready for graduation, all kinds of indicators have told us that the possibility of it flopping are _much_ less than zero, so we're comfortable doing it only at that point.

Comment: I understood that; I was just being flippant.