# Lack of option to close a question because it belongs on another site

Tags: feature-request, questions, close-reasons

In this [question](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1848/how-do-we-add-other-se-sites-as-options-for-flagging), it was said that while this site was in beta, there would not be the specific close option of stating which site a question belonged on. Seeing as how it's been more than 7 years, and this site is now out of beta, can this option be added?

I think this option is quite important because without it, it becomes more likely for a question to be closed for an improper reason and never be moved to the site that it should be on.

Comment: I'm curious what appropriate/natural migration targets would be. For great off topic questions flagging is always an option

Comment: I had a look at past migrations. Up to 2017 there was a clear trend to migrate questions to Biology.SE, but since 2017 it gets more chaotic with questions being migrated to Medical.SE, Law.SE, IPS.SE, Outdoors.SE and even Vegetarianism.SE. so I'm not sure there's a clear migration path.

Comment: There should be a way to have one of the closure options be a textbox to enter the name of any SE site, so there doesn't need to be a list of the most likely sites.

Comment: Are you sure the free text field is a feature "normal" users are supposed to have? I've only encountered it on the site where I'm a mod, but never on any site where I'm a normal user with close privilege. I also haven't found any post on Meta that suggests it's possible.

Comment: @Elmy I hadn't considered that, and that may be the case. If it is, a list of a few of the most common targets would still be loads more useful than Pets.Meta being the only option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This lack is currently intentional for several reasons.

### Don't migrate junk!

That's the first and biggest rule when it comes to migrating questions. If the quality is low, the question is borderline off-topic on *both* sites or it's a "X Y problem" where OP writes X (that belong on a different site) but actually means Y (that belongs here) then a question **shouldn't be migrated at all**.

To ensure these criteria, migration is per default an action only moderators can do. The process may also include checking with the OP what the actual subject of their question is and asking the mod team of the target site if they'd accept the question.

### Migration paths

To reduce the workload of mods, each site can define up to 5 migration paths. This gives non-mod users the possibility to vote to migrate a question without forcing a mod to take action.

Before such a migration path can be defined, the site has to show that there is a history of many questions having been successfully migrated to the target site (without being closed). As of now, Pets doesn't have any clear migration paths at all and the total number of successfully migrated questions is negligible.

**If you think a question should be migrated, please flag the question for mod attention and leave a short comment.**